# Is there a way to use the newer Rails 5 'rails db:migrate' commands in a Rails 4 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a client project that is using Rails 4. They don't have the budget to upgrade at the moment (and we've got higher priorities at the moment). Almost all of my other projects are Rails 5 though, and I find myself typing 'rails db:migrate' almost every time - which of course doesn't work / errors in Rails 4 - and then I'll have to type 'rake db:migrate'. Because I switch projects contexts constantly, its really hard for me to remember to use the old syntax when I'm working on this project.

Is there a way I can bring in that newer syntax into my Rails 4 project without going through the entire process of upgrading the project to Rails 5?

Comment: You can use `rake db:migrate` in both Rails 4 and Rails 5 projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you use both rails version so use rake db:migrate. Because It is work also on rails 5. Rails upgrade its version with newer functionalities but still newer version has many old techniques or functionalities.